# Index Match or using xlookup to look for a value within a table array

Tags: excel, office365

I have a table from column A to D.
I have a value of "Edward" within the table, and it could be anywhere in the table.
I want a formula that can look for the value "Edward" in the table array, and then return a value in the appropriate row in column C as the result

Please help

I have tried using index match and xlookup, but it turns out to unable to look from a table array. It keeps getting error. please help
link of the file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dLMK5IAiFGy2v5zu7txFLkmh3Prca7BG/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104804994821386942619&rtpof=true&sd=true

[Table, input and desired output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tEUV.png)

Comment: What if "Edward" itself is in Column C, what to return then? Please add data sample and desired output

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.
I have added the excel file link, and a screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
=INDEX(Table1[[#All],[ID]],(MATCH(1,MMULT(--(Table1[[#All],[Birthday]:[Phone Number]]=A10),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(Table1[[#All],[Birthday]:[Phone Number]])^0)),0)))
```

or

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,(MATCH(1,MMULT(--($B$1:D7=A10),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($B$1:$D$7)^0)),0)))
```

Keep in mind that it will return only first match.

Result:

[image]